# String or binary data would be truncated. in sql server while insert statement

Tags: sql-server

I have table structure as below..

[image]

but while running insert statement to it shows 
error..

```
INSERT INTO ORD_MST
(ORM_FRCD,ORM_ORID,ORM_MBID,ORM_ORQT,ORM_ORDT,SL_CD)VALUES
('LYM11111111','000174','LYM11111111',2,'01/01/2009','123')
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any triggers?  Also you are inserting 11 characters into `ORM_FRCD` which only allows 10.  `LYM11111111` has a length of 11 but you are trying to insert it into a column that has a max length of 10.

Comment: no sir, there is no trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ORM_FRCD field has length of 10 and you're trying to insert 11 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The values you are inserting must be within the `character_maximum_length` values